# github1s access request provides public access to private repos?

Tags: github

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this question? I want to visualize my private repo on browser with github1s. When I add the corresponding 1s to the https address to view it asks me for authentication token:
[image]

then I'm'asked to provide conwnet access to my private and public repos. If I do does that give everyone access to the private repos?

[image]

Expanding Repositories Public and private says:
This application will be able to read and write all public and private repository data. This includes the following:

Code

Issues

Pull requests

Wikis

Settings

Webhooks and services

Deploy keys

Collaboration invites

[Learn More](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/authorizing-oauth-apps)

Comment: Did you click the arrow next to "public and private"? Does it allow you to change the setting?

Comment: it doesn't allow to change the setting but provides info what the app will be able to read from private and public repo, my original question stands